# Parsing HTML using web workers

Tags: html-parsing, web-worker

I'm parsing large HTML files using the `document.implementation.createHTMLDocument` method. I create new documents, write the HTML onto them, and then use standard document methods to iterate over the trees.

This is proving to be very intensive on the browser and I'm looking for other options.

I was thinking about offloading the work to WebWorkers but as far as I understand they can't access the DOMImplementation interface.

Am I right in my assumptions?

Is there any other efficient alternative I can use?

Answer (score 2):

A minute after writing this question I found the following sentence in the [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) project:

> It even has experimental support for running within browsers, giving you the ability to create a whole DOM Document inside a web worker.

So I guess I will be looking into jsdom, and test if I can gain a performance boost from such approach.

Any other recommendations/thoughts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> This is proving to be very intensive on the browser and I'm looking for other options.

Doing the same thing, but in a web worker would still be intensive, it's just that the UI won't hang while doing it, and you have more glue code/behaviour to write and maintain to wire everything up.

> I create new documents, write the HTML onto them, and then use standard document methods to iterate over the trees.

An alternative that might suite your case, is rather than using DOM-based parsing as you are now, is to use event-based parsing. https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js or https://github.com/marko-js/htmljs-parser might be reasonable starting points. Depending on how you're iterating and what you do with each node, this might prove less resource intensive. Maybe even enough to do it in the browser UI thread.

Of course if it ends up still be too intensive, you can then move it to a web worker to avoid hanging the UI as the document is being processed.